# Accessing image from other server

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, server.mappath

I have image file placed on the one server and application on other server.

I want to access that image, below code I have written:

On default.aspx, I have

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl= "GetImage.aspx?imgName=MyImage.jpg" />
```

and on GetImage.aspx, I have written the below code on page_load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Changing the page's content type to indicate the page is returning an image
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        var imageName = Request.QueryString["imgName"];
        var path = "//SERVER/FOLDER/" + imageName;


        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName) == false))
        {
            // Retrieving the image
            System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg;
            fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path));
            // Writing the image directly to the output stream
            fullSizeImg.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // Cleaning up the image
            fullSizeImg.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error at

> fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path));

Please let me know where I am incorrect. Do I need to anything else other than Server.MapPath ? because my image is on other server.

**EDIT**

- I have image folder in my computer
- I have created a web app in other computer [same network], deployed
  in IIS, image is displayed correctly. With path like
  http://10.67.XX.XX/websiteName/Default.aspx
- but when I am trying to access the same from my comupter or any other
  computer, I am not able to see the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Server.MapPath`. This is used to map virtual paths under your site to physical paths under file system. If the file exists on another server, just access it by name directly, without `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: I tried the same. It's not showing error now. +1 for that. Thanks.

Comment: But still I am not able to see the image, is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: This could be due to network access issues. Write a generic code using the `FileStream` and check whether the file is accessible or not.

Comment: I am sorry, can you guide me about genric code for file checking ?

Comment: do you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use ??

Comment: Just the `FileStream fs = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open )`

Comment: fs is showing file stream without any issue but image is still not available.

Comment: And what exception is thrown if you enclose `Image.FromFile` with `try-catch`?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. It is working fine on the computer where I am developing and deploying it. Both when I am running through Visual Studio and by Http://10.xxxxx/xxx/xx (after deploying)

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite, So, were you able to see (load) the image?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is incorrect because the images reside on a separate server.

So System.Images will not no where the image is.

Secondly you have to use server.Mappath for system images, it requires a windows path i.e. c:\blah\blah\whatever.jpg.
you will need to use \\server\C$\folder\image.jpg this works well with system.image.FromFile

Also saving you can also utilize this.

Cheers