# Load image from an UNC path in network and hide the path

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am having some issue to load some images stocked in a server in my network.

From Windows Explorer, the path is something like this :

```
 \\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\10038P.jpg
```

I tried something like this :

```
<img src= "\\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\10038P.jpg" alt="logo" />
<img src= "file://///192.168.84.52/Distri/Affiche/10038P.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

But it did not work.
Another issue is that when someone try to see the url of the image, I would like it to not show the path `192.168.84.52` . Is it possible to use an aspx page and pass the image name so that it will load the image ?

For exemple something like this

```
 image.aspx/10038P.jpg
```

Well yeah it is not really a parameter,

Comment: This `\\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\10038P.jpg` is probably not going to work the way you might think.  Is this an Intranet site?

Comment: No, it is a public site, the `192.168.84.52` is the ip (in intern) of the server where the images are saved.

Comment: I have the same issue. But, the one I am having is an `intranet` site.   Do you have any idea about how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your best (and simplest) approach might to be to map a virtual directory using the UNC-type paths you have shown.  Then you can address the files in your html in a more 'normal' way (effectively hiding the UNC server name as you've requested).

You could, for instance, map UNC `\\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\` to virtual folder `images` and then reference the image file names from folder `images` in your html.

The following doc describes setting up virtual folders, please note the special instructions for UNC mappings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Your solution seems to do exactly what I need. But right now I am working in local so can't really test. But I found another solution that works as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970755/accessing-image-from-other-server) .

Comment: @DavidTansey, Thanks a lot for the solution!!!  

I was having another issue. I was trying to read images from some particular folder located at "C:\FolderName" on each of the environments (Dev, QA, Prod etc.). The folder (on each environment) was later shared and made accessible using UNG path. When I was running locally, it was running fine. The issue that was happening was I was not able to view the images when running website through IIS of each environment. 
I referred your solution and now it is running fine! Thanks again!!!